# Win32 App flickering when attempting to redraw. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++

I am working on a Tetris game and need to draw it in a WinAPI window. I draw the board using FillRect() function and clear the screen with a self-defined function that also uses FillRect() to clear the screen. It works great but the flickering is killing me! I have tried everything in my power. I tried to repaint the window in the WM_PAINT message but it poses another problem, it doesn't paint the board that it did before. I tried to paint my board again with the same procedure I used to paint the window but can't figure out how to do it, I passed the RECT structure with self-defined co-ordinates to the paint function but all it shows is a blank screen. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Do tell me if this question needs any more clarification.

Comment: `Sleep` does the same thing in a console app as it does here - blocks the current thread for some time.

Comment: Why `Sleep()` shouldn't work for your application? Do you need a Timer instead to keep your GUI thread running?

Comment: Perhaps you need to separate your code to draw versus your business logic to control where blocks are and accepting user input? (different threads)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 1):

Sleep() is not specific to console. It's just the standard windows API to suspend the execution of the current thread for a given amount of time.

You should probably look into [Windows Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Another viable approach, and often more useful for low latency applications like games, is to simply measure time at each iteration of the event loop and advance the game by that. You should use *[High Resolution Time Stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* for this, as regular system wall clock time may jump if the system clock gets adjusted from Internet network time; also wall clock time has some noticeable jitter.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Will have to look into Timers as this is my first time working on win32 app. Another issue boggling me is the clearing screen one. I have gone and created a function of my own drawing a rectangle using FillRect() that draws a white rectangle of window width and height but it flickers alot to the point that the game is unplayable. Any suggestion regarding that would be helpful too and please don't go into anything complex.

Comment: @UzairRiaz: There are two important things to be aware of when writing a game for Windows: If it's graphics heavy and does a lot of animations: Don't use the GDI! It's slow and cumbersome to use for writing games; use DirectX or OpenGL instead. The other important point is, that you have to create your window without a background brush set (regardless of using GDI, DX or GL) to avoid exactly that flickering problem. – *Of course the best thing to do would be not using the Win32 API directly and instead rely on a game application framework, like SDL or SFML.*

Comment: Any suggestion as to how I might create a window without background brush set? I tried to tinker with the hbrBackground property of my window but couldn't exactly figure out what to do.